# Usando jquery-ui para realizar busquedas en un head, con resultados de sugerencias

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

He armado un buscador que va emitiendo sugerencias a medida que vamos ingresando texto en su caja, está insertado en un header con estilos en Bootstrap, para crearlo, he usando php, MySQL, Ajax, JQuery y JQuery-UI (con su js y css), el buscador consta de una caja de texto y un boton de BUSCAR. 
Cuando hago una búsqueda dando clic en el boton BUSCAR, funciona perfecto, redirecciona todos los resultados a una pagina, pero el problema se presenta con las sugerencia... que funciona perfecto, pero al mostrar los resultados... los dos primeros quedan ocultos bajo los estilos del header de Bootstrap y por su puesto mi idea es que estén por encima de este header para poder verlos. Alguna sugerencia?

Codigo del formulario:

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <form action="<?php echo RUTA; ?>Buscador/index.php" method="POST">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buscar" id="buscar" placeholder="Ingrese texto ...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Buscar"/><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Código Ajax.php:

```
    <?php 

    $conexion = conexion($bd_config);
    if (!$conexion) {
        $error = "No hay conexion con la base de datos";
        header('Location: error.php');
    }

class Ajax {

    public $buscador;

    public function Buscar($a) {
        $this->buscador = $db->filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM alquileres WHERE estado = 1 
        AND nombre LIKE '%$this->buscador%' OR claves LIKE '%$this->buscador%';");

        while ($array = $db->recorrer($sql)) {
            $resultado[] = $array['nombre'];
        }

        return $resultado;
    }
}

$busqueda = new Ajax();
echo json_encode($busqueda->Buscar($_GET['term']));

?>
```

Código del Index.php:

```
    <?php 

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    $error = "No hay conexion con la base de datos";
    header('Location: error.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['buscar']) ) {
    $filtro = filter_var($_POST['buscar'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $propiedades = obtener_propiedades_nombre($conexion, $filtro);

    $total_propiedades = $conexion->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_propiedades');
    $total_propiedades = $total_propiedades->fetch()['total_propiedades'];

    if ($total_propiedades > 0) {
        $mensaje_prop = "Se han encontrado " . $total_propiedades . " de resultados en propiedades.";
    } else $mensaje_prop = "No se han encontrado propiedades con el texto ingresado.";

    $servicios = obtener_servicios_nombre($conexion, $filtro);

    $total_servicios = $conexion->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_servicios');
    $total_servicios = $total_servicios->fetch()['total_servicios'];

    if ($total_servicios > 0) {
        $mensaje_serv = "Se han encontrado " . $total_servicios . " de resultados en servicios.";
    } else $mensaje_serv = "No se han encontrado servicios con el texto ingresado.";

} else {
    echo '';
}

require 'index.view.php';

?>
```

Comment: Ricardo, te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites tu pregunta con el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Es posible que se problemas de CSS y solo es necesario que ubiques el DIV donde imprime el resultado y es posible colocarlo para poder ayudarte. Saludos